# ldapsearch - Invalid credentials

Tags: centos, ldap

My goal is to test LDAP authentication from command line. I tried using `ldapsearch` for this.

I'm using `Centos 6.7`

Even though I'm using the correct credentials, the following command fails

```
[user@localhost html]# ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -b "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com" -W
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

The following command works fine without the password field.

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -b "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com"
```

Is there anything I'm missing while trying to supply the password? Could I request help to figure out the problem please?

**UPDATED**

Here's the structure of a user account

```
ldapsearch -x -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3389 -b "ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com" -s sub | more

# john.martin, Users, company.com
dn: uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
uid: john.martin
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: ldapPublicKey
shadowLastChange: 13306
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 509
homeDirectory: /home/john.martin
mail: john.martin@company.com
gecos: john martin
sshPublicKey:: some key
gidNumber: 87
cn: John Martin
```

Here's the query of searching a particular `cn`

```
ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3389 -x -b "dc=company,dc=com" "(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=member_of_this_group))"

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=company,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=member_of_this_group))
# requesting: ALL
#

# member_of_this_group, groups, company.com
dn: cn=member_of_this_group,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: member_of_this_group
description:: some characters bla bla
memberUid: john.martin
memberUid: kyle.miller
memberUid: robert.dangie
memberUid: smith.collins
memberUid: ian.bell
gidNumber: 54787

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Comment: What you're missing is the correct password. Maybe the account doesn't have one.

Comment: Hello - Thank you. The account does have a password. When I try a ssh to the server with the username, it does accept the password. It's an LDAP auth. However, when I try LDAP search it doesn't accept the same password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do not prompt for password than the client will perform an anonymous bind (this is why you do not see an error in the example that does not prompt for the password field).

In the first example, bear in mind that the `-b` argument sets the search base and not the bind DN. You need to use the `-D` argument (for the bind DN). This may sound confusing, but ldapsearch command line tool essentially performs an LDAP BIND followed by an LDAP SEARCH (hence the two arguments).

Comment: Thank you Bertold. I tried the following 2 things - `ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -D "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com" -W` which still complains about invalid credentials. `ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -D "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com" ` throws `unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed`. Anything else I can give a go please?

Comment: Are you user that the bind DN is correct? Is `john.martin` in `ou=Users` or is it in **cn=Users**? It is normal if an LDAP server returns invalid credentials for cases when the bind DN does not actually exist.

Comment: Thank you Bertold. Yes, the user exists. I've updated some details in the question under the `UPDATED` section. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Can you confirm that the user actually has a `userPassword` attribute set? (In all of the examples in the `UPDATED` section you are using anonymous bind). Can you authenticate (bind) as any other user (using the `-D` argument)? Are you using OpenLDAP?

Comment: Thank you Bertold. The situation is that when I login to the unix box, I get prompted for a username/password which authenticates against LDAP. Now, it's the same username/password that I'm using the ldapsearch which is supposed to work but isn't. All the usernames I'm trying to authenticate with have the same problem. All of them can actually login to the UNIX box fine but with ldapsearch, nope, they all get the same authentication error. On the LDAP software,  it is opnldap 2.4.4.0

Comment: The bind in the examples are anonymous , yeah, no doubt. How do I find out out if the `userPassword` attribute is set? The first of the outputs I've updated in the `UPDATED` section shows all the attributes set right? It doesn't have the password attribute from what I see. Is there anything I've done wrong?

Comment: Try:  ldapsearch -x -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3389 -b "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com" -W